# Replacing SSL certificate via SSH with local files

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssl, ssl-certificate

I need to replace a ssl certificate on an Ubuntu webserver which expires soon. My client sent me some certificate files:

- server.key
- server.csr
- intermedio.pem
- CSR_trustico.pem
- Certificato.crt.txt

How can I replace the old certificate with the new via SSH? I've searched about this, but all I can find is the renewal of certificates without local files. How would you replace the certificate?

Comment: Could you add the details for your clients webserver? E.g of it's Apache, nginx, etc. There will be config files telling you where these files go but their location and format will be our best guess without this info

Comment: It's an Apache configuration :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing magic about certificates and keys. They are just regular files on disk.

1. Find the existing key and certificate on the system (it should be referred to in your webserver config)

- In Nginx, the configuration option is called `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key`
- In Apache the configuration options are called `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile`

2. Replace the files using your preferred method (WinSCP and `cp`, copy/paste the contents, etc.)
3. Restart the webservice

You should only need to replace the equivalent of `server.key`, `Certificato.crt` and possibly `intermedio.pem`. The `*.csr` files are not relevant.

---

Next certificate renewal, check with your client if they will allow you to send them a CSR to sign. Certificate keys are secret, and are supposed to be generated on the system where they are used (to avoid leaking the key in transit). The CSR contains all the information needed to generate the certificate, but more importantly, it contains the public version of the private key, and thus it's no problem if it's leaked.

Comment: Thanks very much! I found the files, but some files have another name. For example not "server.csr", but "serverClient.csr". Can I simply change the name of the new files to the name of the old files? I tried this, but after reloading the apache config, the website does not load anymore...

Comment: Yep, again, they're just files. You need to find the file associated with the configuration parameter, you can't mix them up. You won't need the `.csr` files. Check the apache log (error.log) for _why_ it's not working.

Comment: When replacing the old certificate files with the new apache won't start. I get the following error: ` [alias:warn] [pid 13257] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf at line 3 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.`. With the old cert files apache starts with no error. I can't see a connection between ssl certificates and the shown error...

Comment: Oh, I found another error in the log: `SSL Library Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line (Expecting: CERTIFICATE) -- Bad file contents or format - or even just a forgotten SSLCertificateKeyFile?`

Comment: and: `SSL Library Error: error:140AD009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file:PEM lib` ... `Failed to configure certificate xxxx:443:0, check /etc/ssl/certs/xxxx/Certificato.pem`

Comment: Additional: When I open the main .pem file I see `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----`. Did my client sent me the wrong files?

Comment: This is gonna be extremely difficult to debug through a QA format website like SuperUser. Probably another format like #httpd channel on libera.chat is better for this. Also, since you seem to do this professionally, you might want to think about hiring a sysadmin for an hour or two to do this for you, and you can be confident that it'll be done properly.

Comment: The certificate should start with `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` and the key should start with `BEGIN xxx PRIVATE KEY`, if they are PEM encoded. If they're PKCS12 or DER encoded, you will have to use external tooling (like openssl) to determine which file is which.

Comment: I got it to work. My client sent me a txt file with the main certificate data. I had to copy the content of the txt file (BEGIN CERTIFICATE....) to the .pem file..and now it works. Many thanks for your really good explanation! I really appreciate it!